# What did Hans Bethe think of von Neumann's quantum logic?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, philosophy-of-science, quantum-mechanics, mathematical-logic

Nobel laureate Hans Bethe was a friend of mathematician-physicist John von Neumann, and he once said:

"*I have sometimes wondered whether a brain like von Neumann's does not indicate a species superior to that of man*"

and

"*[von Neumann's] brain indicated a new species, an evolution beyond man*"

This indicates that Bethe admired von Neumann's work very much.

My question is: Did he think the same about von Neumann's quantum logic? Did he like it?

Comment: By  "like,"  do you mean that he agreed with the math, or that he agreed with the conclusion, or just that he thought it looked cool?

Comment: There is no way to answer a question stated like this, since Bethe is no longer with us. A proper form would be: "What did Bethe write or say, if anything, about quantum logic?"

Comment: My guess is that he did not think about it. It was a mathematical toy that physicists paid little attention to even in its heyday.